# Visual C++ and XAML Page Inheritance

Tags: visual-c++, winrt-xaml, uwp

I'm developing an Universal Windows App for Windows 10 using Visual C++ with Visual Studio 2015. The language is a constraint due to an old C++ lib we want to use into the application. My goal is to use a base class for all pages from my app.

Base class .h

```
namespace App1 {
    [Windows::Foundation::Metadata::WebHostHidden]
    public ref class MobyMainPage : public Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Page
    {

    internal:
         MobyMainPage();

    };
}
```

Subclass  which has XAML

```
#include "MobyMainPage.h"

namespace App1
{
    public ref class MainPage sealed
    {
    public:
        MainPage();

    };
}
```

The XAML of the subclass

```
<local:MobyMainPage
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns:local="using:App1">

    ...
</local:MobyMainPage>
```

The error occur in the first line of the XAML file. It say that MobyMainPage doesn't exists in App1 namespace.
It's possible to do XAML inheritance in Visual C++ in Universal Windows App ?

Comment: I just tried this and it builds and runs for me. The designer reports the error you are talking about but, the designer is generally useless when using non builtin page types like this, the same is true for C# as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way how I re-use a C++/CX class BasePage among the XAML pages.

**#1 Create a class named BasePage**

> BasePage.h

```
namespace FunctionPointerDemo
{
    public ref class BasePage : public ::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Page
    {
    public:
        void InitializeComponent();
    };
}
```

> BasePage.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "PageBase.h"

using namespace FunctionPointerDemo;

void BasePage::InitializeComponent()
{

}
```

**#2 Create XAML View**

In Visual Studio, add > new item > XAML View, named it as “HelloPage.xaml”.

Add the backend class: HelloPage.xaml.h and HelloPage.xaml.cpp

> HelloPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="FunctionPointerDemo.HelloPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:FunctionPointerDemo"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Button Click="Button_Click">Click Me</Button>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

> HelloPage.xaml.h

```
#pragma once

#include "PageBase.h"

namespace FunctionPointerDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    [::Windows::Foundation::Metadata::WebHostHidden]
    public ref class HelloPage sealed : public BasePage,
        public ::Windows::UI::Xaml::Markup::IComponentConnector,
        public ::Windows::UI::Xaml::Markup::IComponentConnector2
    {
    public:
        HelloPage();
        void InitializeComponent();
        virtual void Connect(int connectionId, ::Platform::Object^ target);
        virtual ::Windows::UI::Xaml::Markup::IComponentConnector^ GetBindingConnector(int connectionId, ::Platform::Object^ target);

    private:
        bool _contentLoaded;
        void Button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e);
    };
}
```

> HelloPage.xaml.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "HelloPage.xaml.h"

using namespace FunctionPointerDemo;

HelloPage::HelloPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}


void FunctionPointerDemo::HelloPage::Button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{

}
```

Comment: It worked thanks :) I noticed that we declared InitializeComponent() in BasePage.h but it's never called by the subclass, I imagine this is just for declaration, I'm right ?

Comment: Another question : I declared a Canvas in my XAML with x:Name="RootCanvas" and it seems that I cannot access to my element from code-behind, like this->RootCanvas. Should I declare all my controls in HelloPage.xaml.h when I want to use it in my code-behind ?