# how to have a User Control inherit from another User Control

Tags: uwp, c++-cx

Recently doing fun personal project in C++/CX UWP.

And I am stuck trying to have a base control class to be used for all my User control.
This base class shouldn't have any XAML and just implementing a DispatcherTimer with OnTick func.
Let's name it TickControlBase

But when I try to have another UserControl inherit from this one, I get only compiling errors.
Let's name it MyUserControl

If TickControlBase inherit from XAML::UserControl, I get an error saying MyUserControl already inherit from XAML::UserControl.
If TickControlBase  do not inherit from a XAML stuff I have other errors, saying that a ref class have to be sealed or inherit from another ref class.
Obvisouly If I sealed it, then no class can inherit from it.

MyUserControl  base class def is generated, so I don't have a control on this. Or maybe in the XAML , but I didn't find how to do it.

Is there a good tutorial somewhere I can read/follow?  I didn't find any with Google, it just find C# stuff.

Thanks
ps : sorry for my average English.

Comment: You can find an example of this in [the ShareSource sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/ShareSource/cs). [ShareCustomData](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/main/Samples/ShareSource/shared/xaml/ShareCustomData.xaml) derives from a non-XAML class SharePage: `<local:SharePage x:Class="SDKTemplate.ShareCustomData" ...>`.

Comment: You link the C# version, I am looking for C++/CX which is more tricky.
So I looked into the cpp folder bu the SharePage is just inheriting from a standard  Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Page , not from another User control. 

public ref class SharePage : Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Page

Am I missing something?

Comment: I found this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613400/visual-c-and-xaml-page-inheritance
But they do it all manually, creating all the file manually, that's really really not convinient.
I am pretty sure there's a way to have VS generate my class properly. I just have to configure the XAML to tell that MyUserControl inherit from TickControl.
But I just can't find any info

Comment: You'll have to adapt SharePage to your specific scenario. Try deriving from UserControl instead of Page.

Comment: you can't it's generated by the XAML when you create a UserControl, in ProjectFolder/Generated Files. In my example I can see MyUserControl.g.h and .hpp that are generated by the XAML. I can't edit those, they are overwritten everytime you recompile.
Did you ever try a C++/CX UWP project, it's very different from C#

Comment: There is a C++/CX version in the cpp directory.